# How to access host internet connection on android emulator

Tags: android

I want to run my windows host pc wifi internet on my android emulator please give some source code example.

Thanks.

Comment: First thing is that don't expect source code by asking for source code and about your question, If there is a internet connection on your PC then the emulator will automatically use that internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

when you launch the emulator, if your system connected to the network the same network will apply to emulator,the wifi indicator in your emulator initially shows wifi "ON" if your system connected to internet..  no need to give special permissions to connect..
you can operate the emulator wifi on and off by pressing F8 button...
and if your Application is using internet then you have to give internet permission in the manifest file..

For more emulator controls we can use : DDMS
and using command prompt : telnet localhost 554

Answer (score -1):

Imdad, do you just want to connect the Internet from your apps on your Emulator? This should work automatically without any changes or code.